# GPO: Folder-redirection from 2 locations: Getting personal folders twice?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, folder-redirection

We have one domain in two locations (connected with vpn). In both locations we are using VMview pools. In both locations we are using GPO for redirecting the user-folder to the file-server at each location. If the users "stay" in their location everything is fine.

If a user from location A connects to the VMview-pool from location B (this is necessary because some software is only installed here) then the folder-redirection is "only" working for some folders. It is working for the "Documents"-Folder. But folders with the settings "Follow the Documents-folder" seem the get duplicated. In the Windows-Explorer there are for example two folders "My Pictures".

On the filesystem I can see the reason: The name of one folder is the german version "Meine Bilder" and one folder has the english name "My Pictures".

All servers are german versions of Windows Server 2012 R2. All "clients" are Windows 8.1 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/74c3c127-f5a2-4942-889a-1c69a0c938f5/folder-redirection-folder-names-not-translated?forum=winserverGP)

There is a gpo-setting for this matter. If this setting is not configured then the english default names are used!
I think that this setting in combination with our upgrades (to 2012-R2) and changes (from citrix to vmview) within the last 2 month led us into the actual situation where some users are affected and some not.

For me this question is solved!